# I'm a window user and I am getting error during installation of laravel. I tried to re-install composer and install it again but nothing worked

Tags: laravel, composer-php, symfony-console

Failed to extract symfony/console: (-1) "C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.EXE" x -bb0 -y "C:\Users\dhars\AppData\Roaming\Composer/vendor/composer/tmp-a9ced416c385f9f7faefbc038d77351a" -o"C:\Users\dhars\AppData\Roaming\Composer/vendor/composer/55b58cf8"
I get this error while installing laravel through command prompt using composer. I used 'composer global require laravel/installer'

Answer (score -1):

You have to disable Windows Defender or other anti-virus programs, and then try to install your new Laravel project again. This error occurs because `symfony/console` is detected as a malware.